# -i parameter to mv command alias in .bashrc is ignored

Tags: linux, bash, command

The title basically says it all. My .bashrc looks like this:

```
alias ls="clear ; ls -l --color --group-directories-first"

alias rm="rm -i"
alias mv="mv -i"
```

The `-i` parameter for the `rm` command works just fine.

I'm using the latest (as of yesterday) Linux Mint (Rebecca), 32-bit, Cinnamon, running in VMWare 10 on a Windows Vista Dell XPS 420 etc etc ask me if you need more info about all that.

Comment: How exactly do you use theses commands? what exactly do you write? when you see it doesn't work?  
  
Also please execute `echo $0` so that we can know exactly which shell you are using

Comment: `-i`: only prompt before overwrite

Comment: I use them as I've always used them. If I have a file called test and I want to rename it test1 I write

`mv test test1`

It renames it without prompting.

Comment: Cyrus: Ah-ha! I thought it would prompt in all situations, no matter what. So it is working after all. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So, Cyrus posted the correct answer in a comment, but not as an answers, so I'll post it here so the question can be closed. `-i` only prompts if a file is about to get overwritten. In other cases there's no need to prompt. Thanks, Cyrus!